# Create Group-able ID perhaps with RANK or ROW_NUMBER to concat row values with elusive sequential alternations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database

Before you make a judgment, this question is different from most of the other questions on this subject. Yes, it's true that I want to concatenate the text in certain rows; however, in most of the other cases, there's an ID value that is the same for each of the rows that a person desires to concatenate. In my case, it appears that I would need to create an ID value, but the problem is elusive because I can't seem to get the ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() functions to partition the values in the way that I'm seeking.

In the data, as the ID increases sequentially, I want to setup a column value like a ROW_NUMBER() but I want its count to reset every time the SpeakerID changes.

I have data that looks like this:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>ConversationLine</th><th>SpeakerName</th><th>SpeakerID</th><th>TeacherLineIfSpeaking</th><th>StudentLineIfSpeaking</th><th>TeacherIDifSpeaking</th><th>StudentIDifSpeaking</th><th>CleanLineID</th><th>ConvID</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td> Hi! Let's look over your problem again. Would you like me to type or talk?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Hi! Let's look over your problem again. Would you like me to type or talk?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td> Hi Gabriela... which phone has the larger area for the screen?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Hi Gabriela... which phone has the larger area for the screen?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td> The new phone right?</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> The new phone right?</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td> correct....</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> correct....</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td> what will you need to do to calculate the area of either screen since we can assume the shape is a rectangle?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> what will you need to do to calculate the area of either screen since we can assume the shape is a rectangle?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td> I don't know ?</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> I don't know ?</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>6</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td> Area of a rectangle = length x width</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Area of a rectangle = length x width</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>7</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td> start with 'difference in areas = '</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> start with 'difference in areas = '</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>8</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td> after you clear your student answer box</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> after you clear your student answer box</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>9</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td> I already did</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> I already did</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>10</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

what I want is like this (notice the new column, second from left):

```html
   <table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>ChatID</th><th>ConversationLine</th><th>SpeakerName</th><th>SpeakerID</th><th>TeacherLineIfSpeaking</th><th>StudentLineIfSpeaking</th><th>TeacherIDifSpeaking</th><th>StudentIDifSpeaking</th><th>CleanLineID</th><th>ConvID</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td> 1</td><td> Hi! Let's look over your problem again. Would you like me to type or talk?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Hi! Let's look over your problem again. Would you like me to type or talk?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td> 1</td><td> Hi Gabriela... which phone has the larger area for the screen?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Hi Gabriela... which phone has the larger area for the screen?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td> 2</td><td> The new phone right?</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> The new phone right?</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td> 3</td><td> correct....</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> correct....</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td> 3</td><td> what will you need to do to calculate the area of either screen since we can assume the shape is a rectangle?</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> what will you need to do to calculate the area of either screen since we can assume the shape is a rectangle?</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td> 4</td><td> I don't know ?</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> I don't know ?</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>6</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td> 5</td><td> Area of a rectangle = length x width</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> Area of a rectangle = length x width</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>7</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td> 5</td><td> start with 'difference in areas = '</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> start with 'difference in areas = '</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>8</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td> 5</td><td> after you clear your student answer box</td><td>Mr. Roberts </td><td>299875</td><td> after you clear your student answer box</td><td>NULL</td><td>299875</td><td>NULL</td><td>9</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td> 6</td><td> I already did</td><td>Gabriela </td><td>9695521</td><td>NULL</td><td> I already did</td><td>NULL</td><td>9695521</td><td>10</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I realize that once I have the ChatID that I can use to group the values, I can use a recursive CTE or STUFF(..) with FOR XML or COALESCE with a variable or a CLR function, etc. to actually perform the concatenation.

I'm running SQL Server 2016.

Also, one other thing I should mention is that there's no predictability regarding how long the dialogue sequences might go. It's possible that a speaker could have a sequence length of 40 consecutive messages (i.e. rows) before the dialogue changes speakers, so techniques that use a fixed number of inner joins are insufficient.
Also, the performance of the solution needs to be reasonable because there are over 16 million rows in this database.

Here's a trimmed down version of the data in a tabular format (minus some of the extra columns that made it not format so well).
Input:

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║   ConversationLine    ║ SpeakerName  ║ SpeakerID ║ CleanLineID ║ ConvID ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║  Hi! Let's look...    ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           1 ║      1 ║
║  2 ║  Hi Gabriela...       ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           2 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║  The new phone right? ║ Gabriela     ║   9695521 ║           3 ║      1 ║
║  4 ║  correct....          ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           4 ║      1 ║
║  5 ║  what will you ...?   ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           5 ║      1 ║
║  6 ║  I don't know ?       ║ Gabriela     ║   9695521 ║           6 ║      1 ║
║  7 ║  Area of  = ...       ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           7 ║      1 ║
║  8 ║  start with ...       ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           8 ║      1 ║
║  9 ║  after you ...        ║ Mr. Roberts  ║    299875 ║           9 ║      1 ║
║ 10 ║  I already did        ║ Gabriela     ║   9695521 ║          10 ║      1 ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩════════╝
```

and the desired output:

```
╔════╦════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ ChatID ║   ConversationLine   ║ SpeakerName ║ SpeakerID ║ CleanLineID ║ ConvID ║
╠════╬════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      1 ║ Hi! Let's look...    ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           1 ║      1 ║
║  2 ║      1 ║ Hi Gabriela...       ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           2 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║      2 ║ The new phone right? ║ Gabriela    ║   9695521 ║           3 ║      1 ║
║  4 ║      3 ║ correct....          ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           4 ║      1 ║
║  5 ║      3 ║ what will you ...?   ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           5 ║      1 ║
║  6 ║      4 ║ I don't know ?       ║ Gabriela    ║   9695521 ║           6 ║      1 ║
║  7 ║      5 ║ Area of  = ...       ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           7 ║      1 ║
║  8 ║      5 ║ start with ...       ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           8 ║      1 ║
║  9 ║      5 ║ after you ...        ║ Mr. Roberts ║    299875 ║           9 ║      1 ║
║ 10 ║      6 ║ I already did        ║ Gabriela    ║   9695521 ║          10 ║      1 ║
╚════╩════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩════════╝
```

Edit: For those interested in the query execution plans of the proposed solutions, here's the estimated query execution plan for @kannan-kandasamy's solution (which you probably need to open in a new window to zoom in and see it because the picture is so wide): 
[image: Estimated query execution plan for solution 2]

Here's the estimated query execution plan for @vkp's solution:
[image: Estimated query execution plan for accepted solution]

Edit 2: Here they are in the same batch:
[image: Both estimated query execution plans]

What's interesting is that when I run them in the same batch, it shows @vkp's solution as requiring 99% of the batch cost. But when I ran both queries to SELECT INTO a new table, @vkp's solution ran in less than 1/5th of the time.

Here are the clustered index scan properties of @kannan-kandasamy's solution:
[image: clustered index scan properties of @kannan-kandasamy's solution]
The clustered index scan properties of @vkp's solution appear to be identical for every statistic and logical value (except it says the estimated operator cost is 1% for @vkp's solution but 91% for @kannan-kandasamy's solution even though the actual operator cost values are identical).

Comment: can you post the input and output in a tabular format?

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: @vkp is that better?

Comment: yes.far better.i ran the previous snippet and understood what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a difference of row numbers approach. (Run the inner-most query to see how consecutive rows with same speaker_id are assigned to the same group). Then get the start id of each group and use `dense_rank` to get the chat_id's as required, in order.

```
select t.*,dense_rank() over(order by id_strt) as chat_id
from (select t.*,min(id) over(partition by grp,speakerid) as id_strt
      from (select t.*
            ,row_number() over(order by id)-row_number() over(partition by speakerid order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

If you just need the chat_id's to identify a group and concatenate values, the inner-most query would suffice. When you are `group`ing by, just `group by grp,speakerid`.

Comment: This is a very fast solution!

Comment: FYI, I needed to edit it to include convID at the end of both PARTITION BY clauses, like this:
( PARTITION BY grp, speakerid, convID ) 
and ( PARTITION BY SpeakerID, convID ORDER BY ID ).
Otherwise, it wouldn't provide a new chat_id if the conversation changed but the same speaker was still speaking (e.g. speaking to a different person).

Comment: @devinbost .. as the question only showed one convID, i was not sure of including it..per what you say you should include it and you've already done so..

Answer (score 1):

You can use lead and windowing sum for achieving this:

```
select *, ChatId = sum(case when speakerid <> NextSpeakerid then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id)+1 from (
    select *, NextSpeakerid = lag(speakerid, 1, null) over(order by id) from #yourgroup
) a
```

Output for this query:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+--------+
| ID | SpeakerName  | speakerid | ChatID |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      1 |
|  2 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      1 |
|  3 | Gabriela     |  19645521 |      2 |
|  4 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      3 |
|  5 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      3 |
|  6 | Gabriela     |  19645521 |      4 |
|  7 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      5 |
|  8 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      5 |
|  9 | Mr. Roberts  |  25239875 |      5 |
| 10 | Gabriela     |  19645521 |      6 |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

Your table:

```
create table #yourgroup (ID int identity(1,1), speakername varchar(20), speakerid int)

insert into #yourgroup ( speakername, speakerid) values
 ('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Gabriela     ', 19645521 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Gabriela     ', 19645521 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Mr. Roberts  ', 25239875 )
,('Gabriela     ', 19645521 )
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this approach, but this method is over 5 times slower than the approach by @vkp, probably due to the SUM operation.

Comment: Technically it should not be slow. Can you post the execution plan? So that we can further check..

Comment: I edited my post to include pictures of the query execution plans.

Comment: Can you try executing both query in same batch? In my query 91% it took on Clustered Index Scan itself...

Comment: any idea why I got those results?

Comment: Can you please provide Clustered index scan properties on that batch execution?

Comment: I'll try to get to this later this week.

Comment: did I provide what you were wanting?

Comment: I'm guessing that the difference in performance had something to do with parallelization.