# How to improve performance of SQL Server query to select rows with value not in subquery with one count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, exists, sql-server-2016

I'm running SQL Server 2016.

I'm trying to eliminate all of the rows for cases where there is only one single row with a particular ConvID (big int) value. My goal ultimately is to also eliminate the last line of conversation when there is an odd number of rows for a particular ConvID value. If I can go directly to the solution of eliminating the last row (ordered by chat_id) for every convID with an odd number of rows (i.e. odd number of rows that have that particular convID value), that would be ideal.

An example of the source data is here in my other question where it's marked as "the desired output": [Create Group-able ID perhaps with RANK or ROW_NUMBER to concat row values with elusive sequential alternations in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816068/create-group-able-id-perhaps-with-rank-or-row-number-to-concat-row-values-with-e/43816180?noredirect=1#comment74793799_43816180)

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatIDWithoutSingleChats
       (chat_id,
        SpeakerName,
        RelativeSpeakerID,
        ConvID,
        customer_id,
        student_id,
        teacher_id,
        district_id,
        school_id,
        classroom_id,
        item_id,
        math_lesson_id,
        Label)
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID AS B
    WHERE B.ConvID NOT IN (SELECT A.ConvID--, COUNT(*) AS Instances
                           FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID AS A
                           GROUP BY A.ConvID
                           HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
    ORDER BY B.chat_id
```

Here's the estimated query execution plan (which you might need to open in an new window and resize to see it entirely):

[image: Estimated query execution plan]

My source table size is approximately 17 million rows, so the query performance needs to be better. I stopped the above query when it ran for over an hour but only inserted 40 rows into the destination table and had 0% completion in the live query statistics panel.

The reason I'm using INSERT INTO rather than SELECT INTO is because the table has an IDENTITY column to auto-increment because eliminating rows puts the IDs all out of order. (Otherwise, I'm not opposed to dropping the table and using a SELECT INTO instead.)

Edit:
Here was my final solution for eliminating rows where there was only a single value of ConvID:

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatIDWithoutSingleChats
FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID c
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID a
                  WHERE a.ConvId = b.ConvId 
                  AND 
                        a.chat_id <> b.chat_id  -- or something that uniquely identifies each row
                  )
```

I also created quite a few partitions and statistics and two indices according to the advice of the SQL Server Database Engine Tuning Advisor. The final query completed in 42 seconds.

Comment: If your problem is not yet solve then you try playing with Row_number ,partition

Comment: It's solved, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.RestoredConversationLinesConcatenated_WithChatID a
                  WHERE a.ConvId = b.ConvId AND 
                        a.ChatId <> b.ChatId  -- or something that uniquely identifies each row
                  );
```

I'm not sure which `id` uniquely identifies each row.  But that is the purpose of `ChatId` -- if that's not the right id, use the right one.

For this to work best, you want an index on `(ConvId, ChatId)` -- a composite index, with the columns in that order.

Comment: This query is very fast, and it gives me the rows that occur once for a given ConvID value, but I'm trying to return the rows excluding those values. In other words, I want the values that don't exist in that result set. I want the rows for cases EXCLUDING those cases where there is only one row for the given ConvId.

Comment: @devinbost . . . You can use `EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: When I did that, it gave me a much smaller result set than I was expecting.

Comment: One doubts,since long.Is it ok to use "*" when I really need all column name or I should mention all column name for the sake of performance.

Comment: @KumarHarsh . . . Don't use `*` in stored procedures or views or other saved queries.  It is safe if the query is being re-compiled each time, so for casual use `*` is fine.

Comment: Thanks.so even if i require all column in my resultset it is better to mention each colum name else stored procedures will be recompile every time.

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly name the columns in stored procedures, etc, because otherwise, if a table definition changes, the stored procedure or database object will still refer to the old table definition, which can cause problems that are very hard to diagnose and debug. 

I only used * here for convenience and to reduce the need to provide long lists of column names for readability for stackoverflow.